# How to combine webscraper and email python code so csv file is sent after it was created from scraper?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, web-scraping, email-attachments

Having a difficult time trying to figure out where to put my email code within my web scraper in order to email myself the csv file that I created from scraped data. (Still new to all of this, so I'm learning how and where to put code within other code)

I attempted to run it after the for loop but it doesn't seem to be correct. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer
from time import sleep

### email modules ###
import smtplib,ssl
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import formatdate
from email import encoders

all_names = []

base_url = "https://www.brownells.com/"
#this is the base url as stated below to help with the page scraper
url = "/optics-mounting/index.htm?f_a=1"
#put first page to scrape url here


#-------making the csv file and titles -------
with open("Brownells_Optics.csv", "w") as csv_file:   #the "w" means to "write" the csv file
    csv_writer = writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(["Title", "Price", "Item Url", "Image"])


    #another loop for the pagination and everything below it has to be indented in it
    while url:

        res = requests.get(f"{base_url}{url}")
        print(f"Now Scraping {base_url}{url}...")
        #gives you feedback of what it is scraping when it is running it

        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
        names = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "media listing"})
        #the whole element that is selected

        #looping through all of the names with a for loop
        for name in names:
            title = name.find(itemprop= "name").get_text()
            #print(title)  <--- each one of these were to see if it would print the right thing
            price = name.find(itemprop= "lowPrice").text.strip()
            #print(price)
            item_url = name.find("a").get("href")
            #can also be written name.find("a")["href"]
            #print(item_url)
            img = name.find("img").get("src")
            #print(img)
            #print(title, price, item_url, img)   #doing this to make sure that all three things we are scraping is what we want
            csv_writer.writerow([title, price, item_url, img])
            #needs to be within and below names and above the scraping next page button code in order for it to be within the true statement

        ### Function to send the email ###
        def send_an_email():
            toaddr = 'who to send email to'    
            me = 'from email' 
            subject = "Put subject here"

            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg['Subject'] = subject
            msg['From'] = me
            msg['To'] = toaddr
            msg.preamble = "test " 
            #msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

            part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
            part.set_payload(open("PUT FILE PATH HERE", "rb").read())
            encoders.encode_base64(part)
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="PUTFILEHERE.csv"')
            msg.attach(part)

            try:
                s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                s.ehlo()
                s.starttls()
                s.ehlo()
                s.login(user = 'PUT EMAIL HERE', password = 'PUT EMAIL PASSWORD HERE')
            #s.send_message(msg)
                s.sendmail(me, toaddr, msg.as_string())
                s.quit()
            #except:
            #   print ("Error: unable to send email")
            except SMTPException as error:
                print ("Error")

            send_an_email()


        #scraping the next page button
        next_btn = soup.find(class_="next").get("href")
        url = next_btn if next_btn else None
        #telling it to click the next page button and then if there is not one, it wont run anymore, making the text above false and stops it
```

Comment: "it does seem to be correct": Please elaborate.

Comment: The web scraper will run and make the csv file on my computer, but the code to send the csv file does not seem to actually email the file that was created. I made sure the file was on the proper path too. Did i indent or put the code in the wrong area?

Comment: "PUT FILE PATH HERE"?

Comment: I had actually replaced that area and other areas with that text to make it easier for others to read

Comment: Any specific reason why you defined `send_email()` inside the scope of the while loop?

Comment: I'll be honest, I was just grasping at straws. I get a little confused on where things go at times.

Comment: I see. Can I give an honest advice that may sound a little harsh? Go through some basic tutorial before trying to stitch together bits of code that you don't understand. It will feel much more rewarding :-)

Comment: I appreciate it. I was thinking the same thing. It has been a while since I did a formal course. I'll for sure need to go back and learn the basics again. I had a general understanding of the scraped code that I had written but have limited myself to that until recently.

Answer (score 1):

The only call to `send_an_email` is *within* `send_an_email`, which means it never actually gets called.

Comment: Is the whole email code in the proper spot, or would you recommend it be in another spot? Also, if it is in the proper spot, where would you suggest I put the "send_an_email"?  Still trying to understand everything so I apologize for the questions